# GWT i18n, change metaTag and reload application

Tags: html, gwt, localization, internationalization

I'm trying to internationalize my GWT application.

I read the tutorials and see some examples.

Is there a way to do the language change without adding the url the tag "?locale=de"

My objective is at the menu login screen, the user selects the languague, and then it reloads.
I managed to do that with the adding of the locale to the url.[Ugly way to me]

I was reading that there is possible with meta tags in Html file.
So i tryed to put that in the html file

It loads in that language, but i can't change no more the language.

Is possible to chage the language only using meta tags?

In code, i can read and chage the meta tag value but when i refresh the change i made is lost

```
    NodeList<Element> tags = Document.get().getElementsByTagName("meta");
    for (int i = 0; i < tags.getLength(); i++) {
        MetaElement metaTag = ((MetaElement) tags.getItem(i));
        System.out.println("metaTag.getName() = " + metaTag.getName());
        System.out.println("metaTag.getContent = " + metaTag.getContent());
        if (metaTag.getName().equals("gwt:property")) {
            metaTag.setContent("locale=de");
        }
    }
    Window.Location.reload();
```

Comment: As far as I remember gwt loads a set of js files specific to chosen locale. That is why reload is required and dynamic change is not possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use cookies to read/write information about your locale instead of meta tag or url.

In your .gwt.xml file

```
<set-configuration-property name="locale.cookie"
    value="GWT_LOCALE" />
```

In you java code to read locale info

```
final String cookieName = LocaleInfo.getLocaleCookieName();
String cookie = Cookies.getCookie( cookieName );
```

In you java code to write locale info

```
private void setLocaleCookie( String locale )
{
    final String cookieName = LocaleInfo.getLocaleCookieName();
    if ( cookieName != null )
    {
        Date expires = new Date();
        expires.setYear( expires.getYear() + 1 );
        Cookies.setCookie( cookieName, locale, expires );
    }
    if ( !control )
    {
        com.google.gwt.user.client.Window.Location.reload();
    }
}
```

**Also Reference**

1) https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideI18nLocale

2) http://learninggwt.blogspot.in/2011/07/gwt-internationalization-and-cookies.html

Comment: Actually, the "locale.cookie" property is read by GWT before onModuleLoad() is invoked. The cookie will be looked up and loaded (if it exists) - therefore the application will be localized upon loading and no additional actions are necessary.